# After using passport.authenticate(), my express server routes all stop responding

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm creating a small demo app to learn user authentication with passport.js, sequelize & express. When I hit my /register endpoint, it creates a user account just fine. Same with if I hit my /logIn endpoint, it'll return the proper user if I give it the correct credentials.

The issue I've run into is that after starting the server up and hitting either the /register or /logIns endpoint the server will stop responding to all GET and POST requests until I restart the server.

Here is my index.js code:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var session = require('express-session')
var passport = require('passport')
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
var flash = require('connect-flash')
var morgan = require('morgan')

var app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(flash())

// Sequelize & Sequelize models

var sequelize = new Sequelize('auth_demo', 'auth_demo', 'auth_demo', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

// Server initialization stuff

require('./config/passport.js')(passport, User)

sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection successfully established')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Unabled to connect:', err)
    })

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App is running on port 3000')
})

// Routes.  

app.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup'),
    function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.user)
})

app.post('/logIn', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("found err") 
            return next(err) 
        }
        if (!user) {
            console.log("didnt find user") 
            return res.redirect('/') 
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            console.log("executing login")
            if (err) { return next(err) }
            console.log(req)
            return res.send(user)
        })
    })(req, res, next)
})

app.get('/loggedInUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
    res.send(req.user)
})

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    res.send('Hello')
})
```

Also, here is the passport.js file to show the strategies:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bCrypt = require('bcrypt')

module.exports = function(passport, User) {
    // Passport stuff

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id)
    })

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        User.findById(user.id, function(err,user) {
            done(err, user)
        })
    })

    // Configure passport strategy

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
        function (username, password, done) {
            var generateHash = function(password) {
                return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null)
            }

            User.findOne({ where: { username: username } }).then(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'That user already exists' })
                } else {
                    console.log("Creating user")
                    var userPassword = generateHash(password)

                    User.create({
                        username: username,
                        password: userPassword
                    })
                    .then(function(newUser) {
                        if (!newUser) {
                            return done(null, false)
                        }
                        if (newUser) {
                            return done(null, newUser)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    ))

    passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
        function (req, username, password, done) {
            var isValidPassword = function(userpass, password) {
                return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass)
            }

            User.findOne({
                where: {
                    username: username
                }
            }).then(function(user) {
                if (!user) {
                    console.log("didnt find user")
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'User does not exist'
                    })
                }

                if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {
                    console.log("bad password")
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Incorrect password'
                    })
                }
                return done(null, user)
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Error:", err)
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Something went wrong with your signin'
                })
            })
        }
    ))
}
```

If I hit that /test endpoint before I try to hit a /logIn endpoint or /register endpoint, it works fine and prints "hello" as expected. However, if I hit the /logIn or /register endpoint right after starting the server up and then try to hit /test the request will hang and not go anywhere at all.

Here is what the express debugger prints in the terminal when it hangs:

```
  express:router dispatching GET /test +4s
  express:router query  : /test +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /test +0ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /test +0ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /test +2ms
  express:router session  : /test +0ms
  express:router initialize  : /test +0ms
  express:router authenticate  : /test +0ms
```

It stops at express:router authenticate, so I'm inclined to believe it's passport.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, posting here just in case anyone else runs into this issue. `User.findById` is promise-based. I don't have a `.then` being invoked afterwards.